# este.parentElement.parentElement.children.tags is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, runtime-error, children

We have a tree which users can open up, it was working fine in explorer 8 and 9 but when we switched to Chrome, it stopped working, the function is like this:

```
function menuopen(este,sm,opt,id) 
{ 
    
    var m=eval(sm); var n;
    if(m[opt][VOPEN]) return;
    
    var parent_elm = este.parentElement.parentElement;
    var all_children = parent_elm.getElementsByTagName('TD');
    var este_TD_children = getImmediateChildren(parent_elm, all_children);
    //var t0=este.parentElement.parentElement.children.tags('TD')[0];
    var t0=este_TD_children[0];
    //var t1=este.parentElement.parentElement.children.tags('TD')[1];
    var t1=este_TD_children[1];
    
    

    if(shownodelines) 
    {
        //t0.children.tags('A')[0].children.tags('IMG')[0].src=menuimg(IMINUS,m[opt][VPOS]);
        var parent_elm2 = t0;
        var all_children2 = parent_elm2.getElementsByTagName('A');
        var A_children = getImmediateChildren(parent_elm2, all_children2);      

        var parent_elm3 = A_children[0];
        var all_children3 = parent_elm2.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
        var IMG_children = getImmediateChildren(parent_elm3, all_children3);        
    
        IMG_children[0].src=menuimg(IMINUS,m[opt][VPOS]);
        
    }
    if(showfoldericon) 
    {
        //also check if we need to over ride the folder if unselectable
        //if(treeRestrictMode==1 && inarray(id,nonSelArr))
        {
            //t1.children.tags('IMG')[0].src=menuimg(IFOLDERNA,IOPEN);
        }
        //else
        {
            //t1.children.tags('IMG')[0].src=menuimg(IFOLDER,IOPEN);
            
            //t1.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0].src=menuimg(IFOLDER,IOPEN);
            var parent_elm4 = t1;
            var all_children4 = parent_elm4.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
            var IMG_children4 = getImmediateChildren(parent_elm4, all_children4);
            IMG_children4[0].src=menuimg(IFOLDER,IOPEN);
            
        }
    }
    
    n=seqname++; 
    t1.innerHTML+=menuhtml(sm+'['+opt+'][VMENU]',n); 
    m[opt][VOPEN]=1; m[opt][VNAME]="m"+n;
    
    for(var i=0;i<m[opt][VMENU].length;i++)
    {
        m[opt][VMENU][i][VPARENT]=m[opt];
    }
    
    if(shownodelines) menubacktd(m[opt],0); 
}
```

and it is called as follow:

```
function menuanchor(este,sm,opt,id) 
{ 
    var m=eval(sm); 
    if(m[opt][VOPEN]) 
    {
        menuclose(este,sm,opt,id); 
    }
    else 
    {
        menuopen(este,sm,opt,id); 
    }
}
```

For some reason, we get this error:

**este.parentElement.parentElement.children.tags is not a function**

so apparently chrome deals with this in a different way or we are using some Microsoft proprietary code that needs to change.

Thanks,

Comment: [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) has no `tags()` method; did you mean `getElementsByTagName()`, maybe? By the way, the use of `eval()` is deprecated.

Comment: I just tried as this: var t1=este.parentElement.parentElement.children.getElementsByTagName('TD')[1];
and got this: este.parentElement.parentElement.children.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Comment: `children` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) is a collection of elements, not a single element; it does not have a `getElementByTagName()` method. You should specify a child index in the collection and use its `getElementByTagName()` method: e.g. `var t1=este.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].getElementsByTagName('TD')[1];`